# Looking for a program that jumps a mouse cursor from the middle of one monitor to another

Tags: display, mouse

I'm looking for a program that will let you make the mouse pointer jump from one monitor to the center of the other monitor with a keyboard shortcut or a gesture. Does this exist? Moving the pointer across the monitors sometimes feels like more trouble than it should be.

Comment: 5 years later, there appears to be another suitable answer here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/268929/176422

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XTool (OSAX) looks like a promising set of scripts:

From the readme:

```
hide mouse v : hide the mouse
    hide mouse

show mouse v : show the mouse
    show mouse

move mouse v : move the mouse to given coordinates
    move mouse [point] : where you want to move the mouse

scroll mouse v
    scroll mouse integer : the amount of scrolling
    [scroll direction vertical | horizontal] : which mouse button

click mouse v
    click mouse [point] : where to do the mouse click
    [times integer] : how many times you want to clik the mouse
    [delay integer] : delay between two mouse clicks
    [using primary button | secondary button | middle button] : which mouse button

position of the mouse v : get the location of the mouse
    position of the mouse
    → point
```

Sources: [Apple Discussion List](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Applescript-users/2007/Feb/msg00303.html), [Direct Download (with readme Docs)](http://lestang.org/osax/XTool/XTool-2.0.dmg.tgz)