# Sending mouse to different monitors for all sides

Tags: display

So I have external monitors set up like this (one vertical)

[image]

And as you can see I am only able to send a mouse to another screen via lower half of each sides. I want to be able to send mouse not just the bottom half but upper half as well.

Is there a way to this? I understand there is a keyboard shortcut approach but I'd prefer to be able to move mouse straight to another monitor.

Comment: RE: "I understand there is a keyboard shortcut approach" -- Just curious, what is the _keyboard shortcut_? I do not believe using the mouse only there is a way to cross boundaries except where they are directly adjacent.

Comment: Check this one: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268697/how-to-quickly-move-mouse-cursor-between-monitors#:~:text=Click%20Add%20New%20Shortcut%20or%20Key%20Sequence%20button.&text=for%20example%2C%20for%20Monitor%2D1,Control%2BShift%2B2%20etc.&text=A%20modal%20window%20will%20appear,Space%20to%20capture%20the%20position.

Comment: zcahfg2, There is nothing in the link of your comment that is a **native** _keyboard shortcut_ and all _keyboard shortcuts_ mentioned require the use of _third-party_ software. In the context of "I understand there is a keyboard shortcut approach" you really should mention this requires the use of _third-party_ software, because without it, one easily assumes that there is a **native** _keyboard shortcut_ and there isn't!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a system limitation when arranging monitors of different resolutions. You *can* change the arrangement to be top aligned instead of bottom aligned, but when moving from the larger monitor to the smaller one you can only cross at the portion of the edge aligned in System Preferences: Displays: Arrangement.